# Font changes when localizing UIButton Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, localization, uibutton

The font changes when I’m trying to localize UIButtons. The localization itself works; I can see the language changing but the font is changing too I tried localizing using base internationalization, localized strings and different pods and the font still changes. I created the UIButtons using the interface builder and set the font in interface builder too, and also tried creating the UIButton programmatically but the font still changes. It only changes for UIButtons, I don’t have this problem with UILabels or UITexfields.

This is what the UIButton looks like before localization:

[Button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8L6j.png)

This is what the UIButton looks like after localization:

[Button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftGdr.png)

This is the code that I use to set the button and localize it programmatically:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button1.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 20)
    
    button1.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("button1", comment: "")), for: .normal)

    
}
```

For localization using the interface builder, I used a pod where you can give a UI element a localized key, but the same issue arises.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows off how you create and localize these buttons? Without seeing the offending code, it'll be really difficult to help figure out what's going on. (If you see this happening when you create the button via code, it'd be helpful to see a snippet which we can try out.)

Comment: In your Storyboard, if you select the button and look at the Attributes inspector in the right sidebar (the three-slider icon), under "Style", what do you see? If the value is not already "Default" and you change it to "Default", does the button appear differently?

Comment: (If so, I can summarize what's going on in a full answer.)

Comment: Yes that was the problem apparently. I just set all the values in the attributes inspector to default, and recreated the button programatically and now it's working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIButton` objects can be configured in two primary ways:

1. Traditionally, via setting attributes on the button and its labels directly (as you do in the code above), or
2. As of iOS 15, via [`UIButton.configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3784627-configuration) to set multiple properties all at once

Although this doesn't appear to be documented overly clearly, when you set a `configuration` on a button, those properties override anything which you might assign yourself to the button's properties. In the case of iOS projects created for iOS 15+, buttons created in storyboards default to being set up with a button configuration in the Attributes inspector: the Plain, Filled, Gray, and Tinted "style" options offered correspond to the static `plain()`, `filled()`, `gray()`, and `tinted()` default button configurations [offered by `UIButton.Configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3784627-configuration).

When one of these styles is set on the `UIButton` in the storyboard, the properties you attempt to set in code are overridden by its configuration. You have two main options:

1. Set the button style to Default in the storyboard, which avoids applying a configuration to the button, and allowing you to use the traditional properties to style the button, or
2. Style the button using its configuration instead

For apps which target iOS versions lower than iOS 15, (1) is the only option (and should be the default in storyboards anyway); but if you choose to go with (2), the configuration equivalent can look something like:

```swift
var attributes = AttributeContainer()
attributes.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 20)

let title = AttributedString(NSLocalizedString("button1", comment: ""), attributes: attributes)
button1.configuration.attributedTitle = title
```